# Export to Excel from GridView gives exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

My code is as below :

**.cs file :**

```
protected void ExporttoExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExportGridToExcel(GridView2, "myExcel");
    }
public void ExportGridToExcel(GridView grdGridView, string fileName)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", fileName));
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

    StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    GridView2.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

The code breaks during execution to give this exception :

```
Control 'GridView2' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

Edit :

I am also pasting the grid view code in .aspx incase its required.

**Grid view code in  .aspx :**

```
 <form id="form2" runat="server">

      <div align="center" class="animated pulse">
        <h1 style="color:#fff400;text-align:center;font-family:Ostrich3;font-size:4vw;" class=" animated pulse" >AUTOMATION RUNS</h1>
      </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" ID = "sourceProducts" runat = "server" ConnectionString = " <%$ ConnectionStrings:testdb %> " SelectCommand = "(my query here)" />

          <div align="center>  

            <asp:GridView ID = "GridView2" runat = "server" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            DataSourceID = "sourceProducts" AutoGenerateColumns = "False" CssClass="mGrid animated fadeInUp" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="25"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="22px" Width="1700px" >
             <RowStyle Height="5px" />
                <Columns> 
                (my columns here)
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
       <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ExporttoExcel" OnClick="ExporttoExcel_Click" /> 
      </for
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception occurs when one tries to export a `GridView` control to `Word`, `Excel`, `PDF`, `CSV` or any other formats. Here the `.net compiler` thinks that the control is not added to the form and is rendered, hence it throws this error even if your `GridView` control is inside a form with `runat = “server”`.

Tell the compiler that the control is rendered explicitly by overriding the `VerifyRenderingInServerForm` event. You can do that by adding the event to the code behind file.

**Code**

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}
```

Comment: Exception changed to this: RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();

Comment: Add `EnableEventValidation = "false"` to `@Page Directive` of the source page.  ie., `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation = "false"`

Comment: It says file format of excel don't match.How do we change the format of excel ?

Comment: There are no exceptions now though :)

Comment: Just try it with changing `.xls` to `.xlsx` in your code.

Comment: .xlsx doesn't work at all. In .xls it said format is different and all rows were coming joined to each other..could not read data